# Putting a network folder in the PATH to easily start scripts

Tags: powershell, path, environment-variables

I would like to be able to start scripts on my network share without specifying the full path.

For example `myscript.ps1` would run `\\myserver\share\folder\folder2\myscript.ps1`

I tried to add `$env:Path += ";\\myserver\share\folder\"` to my profile.ps1 but that didn't work (I've confirmed that my profile.ps1 has been loaded).

What am I doing wrong? And am I even on the right path (pun intended..)?

Comment: Just to check - you did add `folder2` to your path as well didn't you? In your question you only add `folder`!

Comment: Map the network path to a virtual drive and refer it via the virtual drive letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is possible to add `UNC path` in `$env:path` in the way you have done.

But in your example you add

```
$env:Path += ";\\myserver\share\folder\"
```

but you're trying execute a ps1 in

```
\\myserver\share\folder\folder2\
```

that's why doesn't work!

You need to add the full path where your ps1 file is!

```
$env:Path += ";\\myserver\share\folder\folder2"
```

Path values aren't recursive.

Comment: Thank you Christian, but no tab-completion? :(